# Kotlin inner/nested class instantiable only from parent

Tags: kotlin, access-modifiers

Is it possible to translate the following Java snippet into Kotlin? Maintaining guarantees offered by the access modifiers

```java
public class Outer {

    public Inner newInner() {
         return new Inner();
    }

    public static class Inner {
         private Inner() { }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea I thought of. It could be considered slightly abusing abstract/sealed classes:

```
class Outer {

    fun newInner(): Inner = PrivateInner()

    sealed class Inner { // abstract class also works, but you allow subclassing from everywhere
        init {
            if (this !is PrivateInner) {
                throw IllegalStateException("Do not subclass Outer.Inner!")
            }
        }
        
        // implementations go here
    }
    
    private class PrivateInner: Inner()

}
```

A note on subclassing:

I used a runtime check to prevent people from subclassing `Outer.Inner` and instantiating the subclass. Unfortunately with this method, you cannot fully prevent subclassing, and preventing the instantiation of invalid subclasses can only be done at runtime.

A (weak) way to prevent subclassing is to use a `sealed` class. Making `Outer.Inner` sealed prevents subclassing from anywhere that is outside `Outer`'s package.